# Laravel 4 has Many relationship

Tags: laravel-4

I want to count `contributions` rows with is references to `pools` ( a Pool has many Conributions)

```
  $pool->with(array('contributions' => function($q) use($pool){
                $q->where('status', '=', 'completed');
            }))->count();
```

But i can't get the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Contribution model could have:

```
class Contribution extends Eloquent {

   public function pool() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Pool');
   }

}
```

Your Pool model should have:

```
class Pool extends Eloquent {

   public function contributions() {
      return $this->hasMany('Contribution');
   }
```

Query

```
$pool->contributions()->where('status', '=', 'completed')->count();
```

Comment: You don't need the use($pool) if you don't use it in your closure function.

Comment: This is exactly what I Have in my models

Comment: Nice, then you did everything right! But you got it working right, from @MrShibby's answer?

Comment: New issue, when i try to count the number of contributions of each pool inside a foreach i get always the result of the first pool , for example assuming i have 3 pools , and the first contains 18 contributions so I get always 18 for the rest of pools.   it's make a sense for you?

Comment: This is my code : 
  `
         foreach($pools as $pool)
        {

            $count = $pool->whereHas('contributions', function($q){
             $q->where('status', '=', 'completed');
            })->count();
            var_dump($count);
        }
``

Comment: I think you should take a different approach. Do you want to render the counts in a view?

Comment: Yes,
I use a scope inside Pool model and then in the view i do like this :

$pool->countContributions()

Comment: It's hard to judge from this, if you have non default primary keys you might want to set these. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships check the part about foreign keys, might help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$pool->whereHas('contributions', function($q){
    $q->where('status', '=', 'completed');
}))->count();
```